# Tag Concept in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

Anyone Have Idea about Voting concept in codeigniter..... This is My view Page

```
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <p class="font-10">Poll your Vote:</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">No</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn">Maybe</button>
   </div>
 </div><!--row-->

 <!--corosel-->

 <!--ends-->

</div>
</div>
```

Please Explain me with How to register Those Details in database also via Models and controller ..... How to get those details to view in codeigniter

Thanks In advance and explain it briefly .........

Comment: Can you remove the unnecessary code? and properly explain what you want. I can't understand, what you want to do with too long HTML code.

Comment: can you visualize your html, using image or something?

Comment: The question is to broad. The answer would include setting up a database with a proper schema, creating controllers to handle posted data, saving to database etc.. all depending on how you want to use the data.

Comment: Am New to Codeigniter ... Still I cant able to Know From where to start this Polling Concept

Comment: Maybe some help on the way: http://webeasystep.com/blog/view_article/How_to_build_voting_Ajax_system_with_Codeigniter_part_1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oms1ZcWBDY4